# How to display child object view from parent array view

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I have the below which displays a list of products. When I click on a product I would like to see just the product information.

The only way I've managed to get the product info to appear is to use the `{{outlet}}` or `{{render}}` on the parent products template which is not what I want.

```
var App = Ember.Application.create();

App.ApplicationController = Ember.Controller.extend({

});

App.ProductsController = Ember.ArrayController.extend({
    sortProperties: ['id']
});

App.Router.map(function () {
    this.resource('products', function () {
        this.resource('product', { path: ':product_id' });
    });
});

App.ProductsRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    model: function () {
        return App.Products.find();
    }
});

// Models
App.Store = DS.Store.extend({
    revision: 11,
    adapter: 'DS.FixtureAdapter'
});

App.Products = DS.Model.extend({
    title: DS.attr('string'),
    artist: DS.attr('string'),
    image: DS.attr('string'),
    price: DS.attr('number'),
    url: DS.attr('string')
});



App.Products.FIXTURES = [
    {
        id: 1,
        title: 'The Door',
        artist: 'Religious Knives',
        image: 'http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/51og8BkN8jL._SS250_.jpg',
        large_image: 'http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/51og8BkN8jL._SS500_.jpg',
        price: 9.98,
        url: 'http://www.amazon.com/Door-Religious-Knives/dp/B001FGW0UQ/?tag=quirkey-20'
    },
    //etc etc
];

-------------MARKUP------------


<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="products">
                    <span>{{ controller.model.length }} item(s) in stock</span>
                    <div>
                    {{#each product in controller.model}}
                        <div class="item">
                            <div class="item-image">
                                {{#linkTo "product" product}}
                                    <img {{bindAttr src="product.image" alt="product.title"}}>
                                {{/linkTo}}
                            </div>
                            <div class="item-artist">{{product.artist}}</div>
                            <div class="item-title">{{product.title}}</div>
                            <div class="item-price">${{product.price}}</div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    {{/each}}

                  {{render product}}
            </script>

            <script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="product">

                    <div class="item-detail">
                        <div class="item-image">
                            <img {{bindAttr src="large_image" alt="title"}} />
                        </div>
                        <div class="item-info">
                            <div class="item-artist">{{artist}}</div>
                            <div class="item-title">{{title}}</div>
                            <div class="item-price">${{price}}</div>
                            <div class="item-form">

                                <p>
                                    <label>Quantity:</label>
                                    <input type="text" size="2" data-bind="value: quantity" />
                                </p>
                                <p>
                                    <button data-bind="click: $parent.addItem">Add to Cart</button>
                                </p>

                            </div>
                            <div class="item-link"><a {{bindAttr href="url"}}">Buy this item on Amazon</a></div>
                            <div class="back-link"><a href="#/">&laquo; Back to Items</a></div>
                        </div>
                    </div>

            </script>
```

**UPDATE: This kind of works:**

The issue is when going from a product back to products the products are no longer listed

```
App.ProductsRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    model: function () {
        return App.Products.find();
    }
});


App.ProductRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    model: function (params) {
        return App.Products.find(params.product_id);
    },
    renderTemplate: function () {
        this.render('product', {   // the template to render
            into: 'application',                // the template to render into
            outlet: 'main',       // the name of the outlet in that template
        });
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could change change your router mappings to something like this:

```
App.Router.map(function () {
    this.route('products');
    this.route('product', { path: 'product/:product_id' });
});
```

Also consider using an index route which transfers you to a specific location when the page loads:

```
App.IndexRoute = Em.Route.extend({
    redirect: function() {
        this.transitionTo('products');
    }
});
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/schawaska/d2FtF/

Run: http://jsfiddle.net/schawaska/d2FtF/show

Comment: I thought the advice was to keep this type of thing nested? If I dont nest how would I populate the product model if the user went straight to a product id URL eg/ products/3

Comment: Also in your example I think you'd need a separate route to find the individual product?

Comment: I've fixed the fiddle and added the missing things for the other route. In regards to nesting, if you do it this way, you'd have to manually set the template into the correct outlet as you've done in your update (just make sure to do the renderTemplate in the other routes too), or you don't nest the routes.

Comment: Thanks appreciate the help, I'm trying to get into Ember but finding it tough going!

Comment: Yeah, the learning curve is a bit steep in the beginning but once you "get it" you'll be fine. It took me a while to understand a few things and reconcile some of my preconceived ideas about how to use it. A lot of people have had issues with the framework because it has changed a lot since the initial release. It's a lot better and stable now tho